# Как прсотеитровать кейс удаления обработчика в componentWillUnmount?

Tags: reactjs

Как проверить removeEventListener в тестах? Если вдруг удалят этот метод, то должна сработать ошибка. Как проверить этот кусок кода?

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('message', this.getHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать mock-объект window при помощи [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM(`...`);

window.removeEventListener('message', this.getHeight);
```